# macbook pro - red screen 2 weeks after coke on keyboard

Tags: macos, mac, display, keyboard, macbook

Two weeks ago I dropped a cup of coke on keyboard of my Macbook Pro 2009 17".

Instantly the machine self turned off and I turned it upside down.

20 minutes after I dismounted the machine and had no Coke on the boards, just on keyboard.

So I kept machine off and upside down for 24 hours and then it turned on normally.

But yesterday the screen started blinking as red and today it is totally red. I take some pictures with my phone:

[image: photo taken with my phone]
[image: photo taken with my phone]

I made some tests:

- Reset PRAM: not worked
- RESET SCM: not worked
- Take screenshot and view it in another display. It worked fine. Nothing red.
- Try use external display (HDMI). Mac recognizes the display but nothing appears.

Any idea?

Comment: You have damaged your hardware.  You can try replace the ICB and display.

Comment: To narrow it down it'll be the graphics card or the connections to the output devices (screen + HDMI)

Comment: It's a Mac, which means it's hardware is essentially unservicable by the end user. Send it in.